# Esri leaflet plugin only showing North America tile?

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcgis-server, leaflet, esri-leaflet

I am using the [esri-leaflet plugin](https://esri.github.io/esri-leaflet/) to connect to an internally hosted ArcGIS Server.  I have tried using a basemap or tilemap implementation but get the same results with both. The problem is that I am only seeing North America and South America with the same tile starting over again at the prime meridian.  I can find the tiles for europe and Asia by looking at them on the arcgis server so I know they are there.

My ArcGIS Server (set up by someone long gone) is saying we are using spatial reference of 4326.

Leaflet Esri plugin states this -

> Your map service must be published using the Web Mercator Auxiliary Sphere tiling scheme (WKID 102100/3857) and the default scale option used by Google Maps, Bing Maps and ArcGIS Online. Esri Leaflet will not support any other spatial reference for tile layers.

Am I able to use this Esri leaflet plugin or do I need the proj4Leaflet with a new CRS projection setting?

I think I am getting tripped up on the tiling scheme of this pre-existing ArcGis server and don't know how to get a leaflet 2D map to work with it.

Some example code -

```
var crs = L.CRS.EPSG4326;
var map = L.map("map").setView([1,1],1); //just picked a random spot. 
L.esri.tiledMapLayer({
  url: myUrl,
  crs:crs,
  minZoom:0,
  maxZoom:12
}).addTo(map);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Leaflet includes information about the WGS84 coordinate system *generally*, but you'll still need to provide information about the origin and levels of detail of your own cached service in order for it to draw correctly.

```
const myWGS84 = L.CRS.EPSG4326;

// the service metadata advertises the origin and resolutions
myWGS84.origin = [-180,90];
myWGS84.resolutions = [
  0.3515625,
  0.17578125,
  0.087890625
];


var map = L.map('map',{crs: myWGS84}).setView([45,-125], 0);

L.esri.tiledMapLayer({
  url: 'https://services.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/ESRI_Imagery_World_2D/MapServer'
}).addTo(map);
```

[live demo](http://jsbin.com/figawulome/edit?html,output)

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much John Gravois!  This is just what I needed. Providing the resolutions as you described has made Leaflet show both sides of the map!  Thanks again!